# Message queue doesn't accept 0 as an argument

Tags: c, message-queue

So the program works like this. There is a producer, and 4 consumers. The producer generates 6 random numbers and sends them through message queues into the 4 consumers. Each consumer receives them and, immediately
before terminating, should send through another queue one message with mayproduce=0; mayproduce is an integer.

The function in question is:

```
int msgsnd(int msqid, const void *msgp, size_t msgsz, int msgflg);
```

I use the function like this to send mayproduce

```
msgsnd(qid,&mayproduce,sizeof(int),0)
```

when I compile it says "Invalid argument".

If I change mayproduce to other number, for mayproduce=2, the program works fine.

Does anyone know the reason it doesn't accept 0 as an argument?

A sample of the code:

```
mayproduce=2; // if I put 0 here it doesn't work
if(msgsnd(msq2,&mayproduce,tamanho,0)<0) {
   perror("\nConsumidor:Erro ao enviar a mensagem: ");
   exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Show the full error message. And a full code or a somewhat complete snippet at the very least.

Comment: `mayproduce==0` is not like "setting `mayproduce` to another number". It is a comparison which sets `mayproduce` to 0 or 1. Voting to close for lack of MCVE.

Comment: yes it @WeatherVane it was my mistake. I meant mayproduce=0

Comment: Your still need to post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: yes my bad. But the code is somewhat complex.

Comment: So where is the error message ?

Comment: @Ackerman Then remove extraneous sections of code until you have  minimal code issuing the error. There's loads bit apparently irrelevant to your problem yet you still haven't shown the declaration of the message queue ids. Please do try harder to present a [mcve] .

Comment: @EugeneSh. the error message is simply "Invalid argument"

Comment: How do you know it is related to that line then?

Comment: It is suppose to send mayproduce=0 at the end of the process. But it says "invalid argument". If i put mayproduce=something other than 0, it works

Comment: OK, grab a debugger and step through you code to see what is going on. It is very possible the problem is not even in the code presented.

Comment: Alright. We're using signals, child processes, message queues. There is a lot of chance for bugs. Just so I understand, 0 is supposed to be an accepted term for "const void *msgp" right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [msgsnd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgop.2.html)() documentation states:

> ```
>    The msgp argument is a pointer to a caller-defined 
>     structure of the following general form:
>
>        struct msgbuf {
>            long mtype;       /* message type, must be > 0 */
>            char mtext[1];    /* message data */
>        };
> ```

The manpage has a lot more info that you need to read very, very carefully.

So you are not really supposed to send a pointer to an int. You are supposed to create your own struct, where the 1. member is of type `long`, and is used as a message type discriminator that the receiver can look at to determine what kind of message it received.

The size you pass to msgsend() is the size of everything you send that comes after the `mtype` member.

When you perform `msgsnd(qid,&mayproduce,sizeof(int),0)` the following happens:

- The `mayproduce` int is interpreted as the `mtype` member in a `struct msgbuf` , as the documentation says, it cannot be 0
- The sizeof(int) says you will an int in addition to the `long msgtype`. But your `&mayproduce` pointer just points to an a single int, thus you are likely also sending over garbage values grabbed from the stack.

You should do something like:

```
struct MyMsg {
     long mtype;  
     int mayproduce;
};

struct MyMsg msg;
msg.mtype = 1; //or whatever you want > 0
msg.mayproduce = ....; //whatever you want to send.
size_t msgsize = sizeof(struct MyMsg) - sizeof(long);

msgsnd(msq2,&msg,msgsize,0);
```

Comment: Isn't the calculation of `msgsize` vulnerable to padding? If (say) `long` is 8 bytes and `int` is 4. Then `sizeof(struct MyMsg)` is likely to by 16 and end padded. There's no guarantee of that but that's typical for an aligned 64-bit architecture. As a result it will calculate `msgsize=sizeof(struct MyMsg) - offsetof(struct MyMsg, mayproduce);` as 8. Consequently a trap expression will be sent. That's not necessarily harmful if the receiver only looks at the first 4 bytes but isn't `msgsize=sizeof(int)` the right answer?

Comment: @Persixty Why would a trap expression be sent ? We allocated a struct MyMsg, and told msgsnd() to send all 8 bytes starting at `mayproduce` to the end, including padding, if any. I suspect the size calculation isn't quite correct though, there will be an issue if there's padding between `mtype` and `mayproduce` , which will cause an issue when reading into the same struct at the receiving end. The calculation should probably  just be `sizeof(struct MyMsg) - sizeof(long)`

Comment: Maybe I'm misusing the term trap expression... I mean (on a 64-bit aligned architecture) will cause 8 bytes to be sent when only 4 are meaningful.  It will be fine to copy only 4 bytes into the structure at the other.
It doesn't even help if (say) the member type is aligned >`long` and there's padding before the member because I can't see how `msgsend` will be able to do anything other than copy `sizeof(long)+msgsz` around.
Safe (but inefficent) code would go with  `sizeof(struct MyMsg)-sizeof(long)` and pass all padding we're assured that `mtype` is at the start of the `struct`

Comment: @Persixty Yes, we would send 8 bytes, 4 of which would be padding, and that would be no problem, the other end has room for the padding too.

Comment: I agree harmless but unnecessarily inefficient. Why not send 4 bytes? Why so keen to copy junk around? If the padding is at the end - ignore it. If the padding were (unusually) betwen the first and second member I don't see how that calculation can work.

Comment: @Persixty I already mentioned that the calculation was wrong if there's padding between the 2 first members, and have changed the code. The calculation is supposed to generally useful if the struct is altered/more members are added etc. If someone has concern about send a few bytes of padding, they can adjust the calculation accordingly.

Comment: So why send junk around? Just wonderin'. Adding members would be perverse. Just upgrade the member to being a `struct` within the the overall message. Indeed that's the way the manpage leads you 'The mtext field is an array (or other **structure**)' (my emphasis).

Comment: The reason is for ease of exemplification so the code can be used even when the message changes. If you add a `struct Foo {int i; double d;  char c; ;};` as the 2. member instead of the `int` you have a similar issue if you use sizeof(struct Foo);` as that would likely also include some padding. `sizeof(struct MyMsg) - sizeof(long);`  would still work`fine, but also include padding.  If you have an easy to use and understandable general example on how to calculate the proper size, feel free to add it to the answer.

Comment: I think the manpage is **telling** you to use an array or a `struct` so I think the answer is:

`struct MyMsg {
     long mtype;  
     struct mTexts {
      int mayproduce;
     } mText;
} ;`

And use `size_t msgsz=offsetof(struct MyMsg,mText)-sizeof(long)+sizeof(struct mTexts);`. 

Notice this is also protected against padding between mType and the payload. It needs a comment to tell you to add new members in the struct but the other needs one making sure new members are added after may produce.

Comment: But as I keep mentioning if you want to be super safe (but inefficient) `sizeof(struct MyMsg)-sizeof(long)` will be exactly as efficient as the method given in the answer (except protected from mid-padding) and impose fewer constraints on how members are added (i.e. so long as not at the start).